# How to change the completed batches count in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming in one of my applications. Trying to change the completed batch count for the application, but so far unsuccessful. By default the completed batch count is 1000. Can this value be customized per spark application ?

If so can anyone help me understand where to set this value ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per spark documentation, it is `spark.streaming.ui.retainedBatches` property that is default to 1000. Please reference documentation here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-ui